# css border-bottom before padding

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to apply a `border-bottom` before `padding` without inserting an immediate element, i.e., within the `content` box itself? For example, below I created a wrapper `div` with `s3` on the class. Can I avoid this?

Here is a **[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8y83a60/)**.

```css
.top {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.s2 {
  margin: 15px;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
.s3 {
  border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="top">
  <div class="s2">
    s2
  </div>

  <div class="s2">
    <div class="s3">
      wrapped in s3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've been searching around for a solution to this which leads me to think it's not possible. I don't mind using any solution as long as it does not require me positioning items relatively or absolutely. Thought CSS pseudo-element might allow me to do this but it doesn't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You certainly can do this with a pseudo element.

```css
.item {
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    background: #f2f2f2;
}

.item:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
  Hello!
</div>
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o8y83a60/2/)

Comment: Superb answer. Exactly what I was looking for despite the phrasing of the question. To clarify: I didn't mind using pseudo-elements, I just didn't know how to.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any way to use this to make the border act as an underline that is the width of the content. "max-content" and "fit-content" are ignored.

Comment: Nevermind, it works if you add the width to the containing block-type element (div in this case).